# LilyPond on Lion

Tags: macos, music, latex

Did you succeed in installing LilyPond on Lion? How?

After downloading the (precompiled) LilyPond, I am getting:
[image: Lilypond-error]

In plain text:

> LilyPond Error
>
> An unexpected error has occurred during execution of the main script
>
> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Applications/LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/objc/_objc.so,
> 2): Symbol not found: _objc_sync_notify
>
> Referenced from:
> /Applications/LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/objc/_objc.so
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

And yet I duly have:

> ls -l /usr/lib/libobjc*
>
> -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1997152 21 Jul 01:27 /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       15 21 Jul 01:28 /usr/lib/libobjc.dylib -> libobjc.A.dylib

Comment: The problem is not that the file is not there, it is that a "symbol" (code entry point) is no longer there.

Comment: I have not successfully gotten LilyPond to run on Lion.

Comment: @Daniel: I wish they wouldn't just write "for OS X 10.4 and above". It's a little bit too optimistic.

Comment: @JasonSalaz ..So I guess I should have written otool -X /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib . Except that none of the switches I tried in the place of -X would reveal the symbols in a dylib. Anyway, I don't doubt that the symbol in question is indeed missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved in the development version, download from [LilyPond Development Page](http://lilypond.org/development.html) and use at own risk.

Comment: Indeed, LilyPond 2.15.16 works fine on Lion. And it is already compiled, despite being from the development branch.